# How to capitialize first letter of TextFormField in flutter

Tags: flutter, capitalization, flutter-textformfield

I'm trying to capitialize the first letter of Textformfield, for this i'm using the

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
```

but it's not working for `Textformfield`, and works for `textfield`

please help how to do this.

Comment: This question helped me, but mostly to find `TextCapitalization.sentences` ("Defaults to an uppercase keyboard for the first letter of each sentence.")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try with formatter for upper case, in `TextFormField` you just use `UpperCaseTextFormatter` class in input formatters section

```
TextFormField(
            controller: _textEditingController,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              UpperCaseTextFormatter()
            ],
          )
```

Upper text formatter

```
class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: capitalize(newValue.text),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
String capitalize(String value) {
  if(value.trim().isEmpty) return "";
  return "${value[0].toUpperCase()}${value.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: how about capitalize the first letter after full stop?

Comment: It's just for a word

Comment: This does not work if you use two or more capitalized letters ("Peter Pan" becomes "Peter pan") and it does not work if you want to give the option that the first letter can also be not capitalized.

Answer (score 53):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. refer `TextCapitalization`  [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextCapitalization.html)

- Capital first letter `TextCapitalization.words`
- Capital each letter `TextCapitalization.characters`
- Capital first letter of textfield `TextCapitalization.sentences`
- Default lowercase letter of textfield `TextCapitalization.none`

Your Widget:

```
   TextField(
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
        ),
        hintText: 'Search',
      ),
    ),
```

Result screen using `TextCapitalization.words`: [image: image output]

Result screen using `TextCapitalization.characters`: [image]

Result screen using `TextCapitalization.sentences`: [image: images]

Result screen using `TextCapitalization.none`: [image: none image]

Comment: is not woking for desktop...

Comment: Try this `inputFormatters: [
          // This formatter will capitalize the first letter of each word
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'\s\b\w*'))
        ],` hope its work

Answer (score 9):

```
TextFormField(
       textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
       ),
```

This capitalize first letter of each word we type in a TextFormField.

After setting textCapitalization, try rebuilding on your emulator or device instance and check again. Let me know it works then,

Comment: Much better than the current accepted anwser. Clean and simple.

Answer (score 9):

To make it work with TextFormField, you must add

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences // Capital first letter
keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
```

for instance with `keyboardType: TextInputType.name`, it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

The most common issue is that for some reason,

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
```

is incompatible with

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
```

Remove the keyboard type, but leave the textCapitalization: `TextCapitalization.words`, and it'll work as expected.  I consider it a bug or oversight that's been there for years now.

Answer (score 1):

Just compliting [Safeela Nasarin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984159/10213354) answer, which works fine.

Simply make sure to use the embedded emulator keyboard, or the device embedded keyboard depending on your case.
It won't work with external or computer keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a TextFormField instead of a TextField, use:

`textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences`

This will capitalise the first letter. Use it with:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
```

Answer (score 0):

Jahidul Islam answer didn't work for me because I need to capitalize all word in a sentence.
The `textCapitalization` property didn't make the job because it just sugested to the user by auto capitalize the keyboard and my requirements were that the input HAS to be word capitalized.

So I need to implemented it be myself, using the base `TextEditingValue` provided by Jahidul. This CHANGES the input, so the user can't violate our requirements to this field.

Hope it help others.

[image]

```
class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: capitalizeAllWordsInFullSentence(newValue.text),
      // text: capitalizeAllWordsInFullSentence(newValue.text),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}

String capitalizeAllWordsInFullSentence(String str) {
  int i;
  String constructedString = "";
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      constructedString += str[0].toUpperCase();
    } else if (str[i - 1] == ' ') {
      // mandatory to have index>1 !
      constructedString += str[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      constructedString += str[i];
    }
  }
  // print('constructed: $constructedString');
  return constructedString;
}

String capitalize1Word(String value) {
  if (value.trim().isEmpty) return "";
  return "${value[0].toUpperCase()}${value.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue `TextCapitalization.sentences` or `TextCapitalization.words` didn't work for me because of `keyboardType: TextInputType.name`. When I changed it to `keyboardType: TextInputType.text` then `textCapitalization` started to work in both (sentences & words).

Answer (score 0):

The best of all of them is to use onchanged:

```
TextField(
controller: mytext,
onChanged: (value) {               
  mytext.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: value.toUpperCase(), 
      selection: mytext.selection
  );
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capitalize every word of your TextFormField

**Create a method**

```
    String _capitalizeWords(String text) {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
      return text;
    }
    List<String> words = text.split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (words[i].isNotEmpty) {
        words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
      }
    }
    return words.join(' ');
  }
```

**In your TextFormField**
In onchange : property you can call this method which will return capitalize words.

```
    TextFormField(
        other properties ...
        onChanged: (text) {
                   .textController.value = textController.value.copyWith(
                    text: _capitalizeWords(text),
                    selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: text.length),
                    );
                },
...
),
```